# $\frac12{(-b+\sqrt{b^2-4c})}$: Change to the first order (1.2.8, from book Calculus for the Ambitious)

Tags: calculus

I've been trying to solve the following problem (1.2.8) from the book Calculus for the Ambitious (available legally free here https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~twk/).

**Exercise 1.2.8** *If* $b^2 > 4c$ *, the quadratic equation* $x^2 + bx + c = 0$ has two roots:

$\frac{(-b+\sqrt(b^2-4c))}{2}$ and $\frac{(-b-\sqrt(b^2-4c))}{2}$

*What is the effect of small changes in b and c?*

I've been trying to solve as I did with the other problems (tackling one equation first):

First, write the formula with the $\delta$ of the quantities.
$R + \delta(R) = \frac{-(b+\delta(b))+\sqrt{(b+\delta(b))^2-4(c+\delta(c))}}{2}$

Second I rearrange, remove the +second order terms, and try to solve algebraically.
$2R + 2\delta(R) +(b+\delta(b)) = \sqrt{(b+\delta(b))^2-4(c+\delta(c))}$

Third, I square both sides, and this is where I get lost, trying to solve for $\delta(b)$ and $\delta(c)$.

($2R + 2\delta(R) +b+\delta(b))^2 = (b+\delta(b))^2-4(c+\delta(c))$

Is this the right way to follow, and then I have to work on my algebra skills? Or did I miss something in the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

The effect can be obtained by perturbing the equation $x^2+bx+c=0$ as follows,

$$(R+\delta_R)^2+(b+\delta_b)(R+\delta_R)+(c+\delta_c)=0$$

which leads to,

$$(2R+b)\delta_R+(R\delta_b+\delta_c)=0$$

Thus, the effect on the root $R$ due to small changes $\delta_b$ and $\delta_c$ is

$$\delta_R=-\frac{R\delta_b+\delta_c}{2R+b}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a problem with partial and total derivatives.

You have 
$$r_\pm=\frac{1}{2} \left(-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4 c}\right)$$
$$dr=\frac{\partial r}{\partial b}db+\frac{\partial r}{\partial c}dc$$ then, going from $d$ to $\Delta$
$$\Delta r=\frac{\partial r}{\partial b}\Delta b+\frac{\partial r}{\partial c}\Delta c$$